# EF schema specified is not valid. Type x is not available

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 classes TypeMetadata and MethodMetadata

```
public class TypeMetadata
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<MethodMetadata> Methods {get; set;}
}

public class MethodMetadata
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<TypeMetadata> GenericArguments {get; set;}
    public ICollection<TypeMetadata> Attributes {get; set;}
}
```

And this is OnModelCreating method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<MethodMetadata>().HasMany(m => m.AttributesMetadata).WithMany(c => c.Methods).Map(cs => cs.ToTable("MethodMetadataAttributes"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<MethodMetadata>().HasMany(m => m.GenericArguments).WithMany(c => c.Methods).Map(cs => cs.ToTable("MethodMetadataGenericArguments"));
}
```

It gives me Schema specified is not valid. MethodMetadata_Attributes was not loaded because TypeMetadata is not available.

When there is only one property (Attributes or GenericArguments) it goes not so bad.
How should I change OnModelCreating method?

Comment: I you have 2 collections connected to `MethodMetadata`
It suppose to have 2 collections in `TypeMetadata` as well.

Comment: It works indeed but isn't it possible to avoid having an extra collection?

Comment: The model you describes it something that EF will convert into DB Schema.
You suppose to have 2 Many-to-Many relations between the tables, it should be fully defined from both tables. It's how EF works.

What is the issue of having both?

Comment: There is no issue. I just wanted to know if it could be done without both. Thank you very much